Cannot run test cases in Android Studio, "Could not find or load main class Files/Microsoft"
Error: Could not find or load main class Files/Microsoft
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files/Microsoft
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 2.
Gradle version: 8.6
AGP: 8.4.2
using the following  testImplementation libraries:
juint:4.13.2
robotoelectric:4.10.3
Already tried the fixes in this but no success.
